# Clearing setInterval issue

Tags: jquery, animation, background-image, background-position

I am having some difficulties running multiple animation in Safari without the browser lagging. My animations are smooth in all other browsers.

I'm not sure whether it has something to do with my script:

```
var looping;

function loop()
{
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if( scrollTop > 300 && scrollTop < 1001 )
    {
        looping = setInterval(function()
        {
            $('.page.active .strip').stop().animate(
            {
                'background-position': '-=100px'
            },1000,'linear');
        },1000);
    }
    else if( scrollTop < 301 || scrollTop > 1000 )
    {
    clearInterval(looping);
    $('.page.active .strip').stop();
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to make an infinite rotating image.

I have tried both the following to make the animation stop:

```
clearInterval(looping);
$('.page.active .strip').stop();
```

Which does not work. As you can see above I want the animation only to run once the strip is visible to the user.

At the same time I have this animation running.

```
function loadLandingSlider()
{
    totalImg = $('.page.active #rotating-item-wrapper img').length;

    rotate = setInterval(
    function() 
    {
        loadImg();
    }, 3000);
}

function loadImg()
{
    $('.page.active .rotating-item').fadeOut(1000);
    $('.page.active #rot' + counter).fadeIn(1000);  

    if(counter == totalImg) counter = 1;
    else counter ++;
}
```

This is just a basic image fadeOut gallery

**I have tried replacing the script with css3 animations, but that made it lag even more**

*Any help appreciated!*

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle demo if possible?

Comment: the problem is that there's quite a bit of code. But I'll add it now

Comment: How about adding `clearInterval(looping);` as the first line in `if` block in `loop()`. Can you try that? i.e. clearInterval(looping); in both if and else block.

Comment: Starting animations inside a setInterval that have the same duration of the interval could cause problems. The timing is not exact enough, it's likely that the animation isn't quite finished when the next interval happens, so they begin to queue up. Not to mention, why would you animate in increments of 100 instead of just animating the full length?

Comment: @KevinB The reason for this method is to make an infinite loop. I can understand where you're coming from with the timing, but I have yet to find an easier solution for this.

Comment: @Dirk, thanks for the simple working solution. It's always something small. :-)

Comment: A self executing function? in the complete callback of the animate, execut the function that starts it up again.

Comment: So is that working for you? I would add it as answer then.

Comment: @KevinB I think I have done so previously. I think because of the lagging animation, I moved to different solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your loop look like this ...

Add `clearInterval(looping);` as the first line in if block in `loop()`. Can you try that? i.e. `clearInterval(looping);` in both if and else block.

```
var looping;

function loop()
{
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  clearInterval(looping);
  if( scrollTop > 300 && scrollTop < 1001 )
  {
    looping = setInterval(function()
    {
        $('.page.active .strip').stop().animate(
        {
            'background-position': '-=100px'
        },1000,'linear');
    },1000);
  }
  else if( scrollTop < 301 || scrollTop > 1000 )
  {
    $('.page.active .strip').stop();
  }
}
```

Comment: I found that adding the clearInterval on the first line in the function, the else block is unnecessary. But thanks :-)

Comment: Yeah, you can improvise it.